# Is it possible to use a free certificate for hybrid deployment of Office365 and exchange 2010?

Tags: certificate, office365, exchange-server-2010, hybrid

this sounds not descent, but i just want to avoid those complicated process to get a certificate to use for hybrid deployment, and, of course, free of charges.
Anybody know how to hack this?
We can talk about it.